# My xampp apache is not working

Tags: xampp

I just installed xampp on my laptop but I have some issue running apache. It says busy port 80. I have unchecked port 80 on skype and change the apache config to 81.

```
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    Windows Version: Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    XAMPP Version: 1.8.2
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\users\dean\desktop\m\"
3:05:11 p.m.  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
3:06:43 p.m.  [main]    All prerequisites found
3:06:43 p.m.  [main]    Initializing Modules
3:06:44 p.m.  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
3:06:44 p.m.  [main]    Control Panel Ready
3:06:49 p.m.  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
3:06:50 p.m.  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
3:06:50 p.m.  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:06:50 p.m.  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:06:50 p.m.  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:06:50 p.m.  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:06:50 p.m.  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:06:50 p.m.  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
3:06:50 p.m.  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

The log says it is not being ran with admin rights. Try right-clicking the xampp_start.exe file and clicking 'Run as Administrator'

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your apache folder inside the xampp folder (xampp\apache) and running the apache_uninstallservice.bat and then apache_installservice.bat. If this doesn't work then hopefully someone else can help cause I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

In windows, disable the already running 'World Wide Web Publishing' service which is running at port 80 ( and is blocking Apache to start). To do so Start >> Run >> services.msc >> lookout for 'World Wide Web Publishing' service >> Stop the service and set the start type to 'Disabled'.

Then try starting the xampp Apache again.

Answer (score -1):

If you done hidden everything (Except or include htdocs) on your xampp folder in C drive (such as C:\xampp) than please un-hidden everything. That may be helpful.